# Adding Windows Azure Mobile Service to the Mobile Application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, windows-mobile

I am trying my hands on Windows Azure Mobile Services. My environment is Visual Studio 2010. Azure SDK is installed. And operating system is Windows 7.

I have created a Windows Azure Mobile Services and also created the sample database and the table as instructed while creating the service.

On the other hand I have installed Mobile SDK on my Visual Studio 2010. The instructions from the Azure site says, "add a reference to the "Windows Azure Mobile Services Client" extension"

When I try to add the reference to my project inside the Visual Studio, I do not find any package by name Windows Azure Mobile Services Client or anything as such. Can some one please help me by letting me know the path where the dll is? Or if there is anything I have missed while trying to add the reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Windows Azure Mobile Service SDK is not supported for Windows 7 and VS 2010. On Windows platform, You can only build mobile applications for Windows 8 (Windows Store Apps) using VS 2012.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Gaurav's answer, Windows Azure Mobile Svcs does support Windows Phone 8 (in addition to Windows Store apps), but not Windows Phone 7. You can still retrieve data from WAMS from any client via a REST call though.